# Date format parser error

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse the following string

```
Tue Mar 23 22:59:59 UTC 2027
```

into a DateTime with the following code

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact( dateString, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

But I get

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT: Thank you for closing the question. Just wanted to notify that the referenced question does not answer this one.

Comment: try to use  `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")`

Comment: All you need to do is this: `var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss UTC yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @RosdiKasim: thank you very much. your comment solved the problem.